# How to write and combine multiple source files for a project in MASM?

Tags: winapi, assembly, x86, linker, masm

Pretty new to assembly, having fun poking at it. I am wanting to split the functionality of my program across multiple files, specifically by grouping similar functions together for organization. These other files would be called by the main file (and hopefully even other non-main files). I haven't yet managed to do so, and would like help.

I am not using an IDE, preferring to use notepad++, ml.exe, and link.exe (from MASM folder) to write, assemble, and link the program myself. Most online resources I have looked at assume Visual Studio, and give code that doesn't work for me, or maybe is incomplete b/c the IDE does something else. I do not intend to start using an IDE.

I would like to learn the "best" way, meaning, the way that is most useful for future projects. Can I set it up in such a way that I can just copy the file and write a couple lines of code to use it in a different project in the future? Or maybe that's bad practice and I should learn a more standard method instead? I understand this platform is not for opinionated questions, and I'm hoping this question is more factually based than opinion.

All useful info I can think of:      
Language: Masm assembly x86          
Computer: 64 bit Windows

Code:    
RUN.bat

```
@echo off

ml /c /coff /Zi /Fl Driver.asm
ml /c /coff /Zi /Fl Utils.asm

link /debug /subsystem:console /entry:start /out:Driver.exe Utils.obj Driver.obj \masm32\lib\kernel32.lib

Driver.exe

pause
```

Driver.asm

```
.386
.model flat
.stack 100h

ExitProcess PROTO Near32 STDCALL, dwExitCode:DWORD
ClearRegs PROTO

.DATA
.CODE

PUBLIC _start
_start:

    Main PROC
        MOV EAX, 0
        INVOKE ClearRegs
        INVOKE ExitProcess, 0
    Main ENDP

END
```

Utils.asm

```
.386
.model flat
.stack 100h

OPTION PROC:PRIVATE ; Set procedures to private by default

PUBLIC ClearRegs

.DATA
.CODE
    
    ClearRegs PROC C
        XOR EAX, EAX
        XOR EBX, EBX
        XOR ECX, ECX
        XOR EDX, EDX
        XOR ESI, ESI
        XOR EDI, EDI
        RET
    ClearRegs ENDP

END
```

Terminal output

```
Microsoft (R) Macro Assembler Version 6.14.8444
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corp 1981-1997.  All rights reserved.

 Assembling: Driver.asm
Microsoft (R) Macro Assembler Version 6.14.8444
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corp 1981-1997.  All rights reserved.

 Assembling: Utils.asm
Microsoft (R) Incremental Linker Version 5.12.8078
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corp 1992-1998. All rights reserved.

Driver.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol ClearRegs
Driver.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals
'Driver.exe' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
Press any key to continue . . .
```

Comment: Another way to enable code-reuse is to make a library (static or dynamic).  That avoids duplicating the source for cases where you don't need to change the implementation of a function at all.  But within a single project, yeah, you can make multiple `.asm` files, assemble them separately, and link them together into a `.exe`.

Comment: Are you asking *how* to do that, or are you asking if it's a good idea?  I assume you can just pass multiple `.obj` files to `link`.  You seem to have a `.bat` file with a simplistic pattern that assumes one .obj, so use a better build system (like `make`) or improve your .bat to work if you use `*.asm` or something.

Comment: I was asking both how and if to do this. Taking your advice, I assembled each separately, which worked fine, then tried to pass both .obj to link and I get unresolved external symbols (the name of the methods). Make appears to be part of something called GNU, which I don't think I want (should I get it?). I started researching libraries, and found that I don't have the lib.exe in MASM folder, leading to the discovery that I was given a simpler version by a teacher. Is using .lib files the way I should go?

Comment: Those undefined symbols... did you mark them `public` in the file they are declared in so that they are visible to other modules (object files) when linking is done?

Comment: I believe so. I have added code to the original question as well as terminal output for you and others.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Now that your question has been updated with a minimal, complete, verifiable example some specific problems can be identified. When you declare a function with `PROC` there is a language naming and calling convention applied to each function. Not specifying one associates no special processing.

You can specify a default language with the model directive as a second parameter. In both your files you have used:

```
.model flat
```

So you haven't associated a default language. You have defined `ClearRegs` as:

```
ClearRegs PROC C
[snip]
ClearRegs ENDP
```

The problem here is that `PROC C` specifies the *C* language calling convention and naming convention. With COFF format (32-bit) the *C* naming convention requires an underscore (`_`) to be prepended to the beginning of the function name. If you were to generate a MAP file you'd discover that the Function name exported from *utils.asm* is actually `_ClearRegs` and not `ClearRegs`.

There are a number of ways to fix this. You can choose not to add a default language to the `.model` directive and tell `Driver.asm` that `ClearRegs` is defined as a *C* PROTOtype by changing:

```
ClearRegs PROTO
```

to

```
ClearRegs PROTO C
```

So now *utils.asm* is exporting `_ClearRegs` and *Driver.asm* is importing `_ClearRegs` as both sides match and MASM will handle adding the extra underscore. `INVOKE ClearRegs` will use the naming convention associated with the `PROTO` statement which says the language is *C* so it will add the extra `_` for you.

This brings up an additional change you can make. An `END` directive can be used to specify the entry point to your program rather than using `/entry:<name>` on the linker command line. The entry point has to have a name that starts with an `_` to satisfy the linker.

You currently use this in *Driver.asm*:

```
PUBLIC _start
_start:

Main PROC
    [snip]
Main ENDP

END
```

And you use `/entry:start` when linking. You could change this to be:

```
_Main PROC
    [snip]
_Main ENDP

END _Main   ; END with a function name tells linker to use _Main as program entry point
```

When linking you can now remove the `/entry` option altogether and you don't need the `_start` label anymore. We can do better though. The entry point called by the MS *C* Runtime startup assumes the function is following the *C* language naming and calling convention. What is preferable is to do this:

```
Main PROC C
    [snip]
Main ENDP

END Main   ; END with a function name tells linker to use _Main as program entry point
```

If you intend to make all your functions `PROC C` then you can avoid specifying `C` in  most places by changing the default language in both *Utils.asm* and *Driver.asm* by changing:

```
.model flat
```

to:

```
.model flat, C
```

This will change the default for `PROTO` statements, `PUBLIC` statements specifying a function defined with `PROC` and `PROC` statements themselves. Your code in *Driver.asm* could look like:

```
.386
.model flat, C
.stack 100h

ExitProcess PROTO Near32 STDCALL, dwExitCode:DWORD
ClearRegs PROTO

.DATA
.CODE

Main PROC
    MOV EAX, 0
    INVOKE ClearRegs
    INVOKE ExitProcess, 0
Main ENDP

END Main
```

*Utils.asm* could look like:

```
.386
.model flat, C
.stack 100h

OPTION PROC:PRIVATE ; Set procedures to private by default

PUBLIC ClearRegs

.DATA
.CODE
    
ClearRegs PROC
    XOR EAX, EAX
    XOR EBX, EBX
    XOR ECX, ECX
    XOR EDX, EDX
    XOR ESI, ESI
    XOR EDI, EDI
    RET
ClearRegs ENDP

END
```

And you'd link with:

```
link /debug /subsystem:console /out:Driver.exe Utils.obj Driver.obj \masm32\lib\kernel32.lib
```

Comment: Thank you very much, this is an excellent answer. You saved me from needing to use  lib.exe and helped me remove the _start label, something I was honestly hating to use. A couple of loops to assemble all .asm files and link them together, and my .bat file is fine as well! You sir, are truly a scholar and a gentleman.