# I'm trying to link assembly code to C++, but I don't know how it works

Tags: c++, assembly, masm

I want to link assembly code to C++, and below is my code.

This is .cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include <time.h>
using namespace std;

extern "C" {int IndexOf(long searchVal, long array[], unsigned count); }

int main()
{
//Fill an array with pseudorandon integers.
const unsigned  ARRAY_SIZE = 100000;
const unsigned  LOOP_SIZE = 100000;

char F[] = "false";
char T[] = "true";
char* boolstr[] = {F,T};

long array[ARRAY_SIZE];
for (unsigned i = 0; i < ARRAY_SIZE; i++)
    array[i] = rand();

long searchval;
time_t startTime, endTime;
cout << "Enter an integer value to find:";
cin >> searchval;
cout << "Please wait... \n";

//Test the Assembly language function.
time(&startTime);
int count = 0;
for (unsigned n = 0; n < LOOP_SIZE; n++)
    count = IndexOf(searchval, array, ARRAY_SIZE);  //Here

bool found = count != -1;

time(&endTime);
cout << "Elapsed ASM time: " << long(endTime - startTime)
    << " seconds. Found = " << boolstr[found] << endl;

return 0;
}
```

This is .asm

```
;IndexOf function (IndexOf.asm)

.586
.model flat, C

Indexof PROTO,
srchval:DWORD, arrayPtr: PTR DWORD, count: DWORD

.code
;---------------------------------------------------------------------
IndexOf PROC USES ecx esi edi,
srchval: DWORD, arrayPtr : PTR DWORD, count: DWORD
;
;Performs a linear search of a 32-bit integer array,
;looking for a specific value. If the value is found,
;the matching index position is returned in EAX;
;otherwise, EAX equals -1.
;---------------------------------------------------------------------
NOT_FOUND = -1

mov eax, srchval            ; search value
mov ecx, count              ; array size
mov esi, arrayPtr           ; pointer to array
mov edi, 0                  ;index

L1: 
cmp [esi+edi*4], eax
je found
inc edi
loop L1
notFound:
mov al, NOT_FOUND
jmp short exit

found:
mov eax, edi

exit:
ret
IndexOf ENDP
END
```

It's same code on the textbook Assembly Language by Irvine.
And I already set the build customizations, and check the box next to masm.
I also set .asm Properties, then change the item type to Microsoft Macro Assembler.

I don't know how to link these two files together.
I'm wondering whether the problem is less of some code in .cpp or .asm.

Please help me:(
thank!!

Comment: What does the book **Assembly Language** say you need to do to link the object code of those two source files?

Comment: @Eljay I wrote the code according to the book. In addition, the .cpp file in the book wrote an extra line #include "IndexOf.h".But there's no such header file:(

Comment: The line with `extern "C"` belongs in `IndexOf.h`, if you want to have a separate header file.

Answer (score 0):

I am not giving an exact answer here,  this answer might be a little rough, but in this link pay attention the the link command from the question and if you can get your self two obj files for the cpp and asm I think it should work.  If you are learning you could try making an nmake file.  I think some assembly programmers do that.  I have the Irvine book and I don't remember him mixing c++ and asm

[How to write and combine multiple source files for a project in MASM?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62618027/how-to-write-and-combine-multiple-source-files-for-a-project-in-masm)

It is a little more complicated than what I am saying here, but basically to mix the two they have to be using the same calling convention.  On Windows I *think* that is __stdcall basically the program needs to know how the use the stack between the two source files.  Side note, most of the stuff in win32 api headers boils down to __stdcall.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/stdcall?view=msvc-170

This is not a pro answer, but it might help

PS I didn't notice your comment of the IndexOf.h, try getting rid of your { } on extern "C" line, I *think* that is basically what you would find in header file,  header file typically declare functions, but do not define functions

[image: program output]

Edit additional info:

For your last comment, if you are asking what think you are asking, it works like this: the extern "C" int IndexOf(long searchVal, long array[], unsigned count); is called a function prototype, that means it is telling the compiler that a function with this "indexof" signature exists, it does not however mean the function is implemented or define what that function does.  Your implementation is in asm, but it could easily be replaced with c++ as long as the signature is the same.  I am guessing one of the errors you may have gotten along the way is a linker error for IndexOf definition not found, that just means your C++ is saying, hey you said we have a indexOf function and I need it but cannot find it.  That happens at the linking stage where the object files for the C++ and asm are linked to create the exe file.  So yes if you are using Vs you can use your debugger to STEP INTO your assembly code of indexOf or even put the break point in asm file its self.
Side note: in windows (and i guess in linux) for example when programming against the API (functions of windows) your could step into the assembler code, but is is not really source code, it is just the machine code that has been linked into your exe, sometimes you can see that in the stack trace, for example all Windows exes start with ntdll.dll as that contains the process loader.  As Linux is open source I guess you code step into the os source if you had it loaded and MS could step into the code of Windows as they own it.  It comes down to debugging symbols, look for the pdb files (on Windows platforms with MASM/Vs) in your project folder after building the project.

Comment: Also, I just tried you program the asm file function is as indexof but your c++ is calling indexOf, it is case sensitive and you have one lower case o and one upper case O.  I am going to attach a screen shot of your programs output, I never studied it to know what it should do.

Comment: Thanks a lot!! I just got rid of {} on extern "C", put the extern "C" function's declaration in "IndexOf.h" and put extern "C" function's definition in .cpp. But I also have a problem that is when I compile this code, it execute to "count = IndexOf(searchval, array, ARRAY_SIZE);"this line, it will go to .asm and do the "IndexOf PROC"?? or just execute the IndexOf function in .cpp?? I'm sorry that I'm just a newbie.